# Select the most recent row with Min value from the last 100 rows in sql table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 100,000 records. I want to return the row with the most recent Low value of a specific field from the last 100 records.

```
SELECT * From streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC where Low = 
    (select min(Low) FROM streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC)
```

Returns the row(s) with lowest value in column "Low" in the whole table.
But I need to only return the most recent row of the last 100 inserted rows of my table.
Speed is of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 * 
From (select Top 100 * from streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC order by OHLCid desc) as x
where Low = 
(select min(Low) FROM (select Top 100 * from streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC order by OHLCid desc) as temp)
```

This assumes there is a auto incrementing column called id, if there isn't you will need some sort of date column to determine which rows came first.

Comment: fixed, it needed an alias name for the sub query

Comment: So you only want to return a single row?

Comment: please see changes made, that will return the most recent row from the 100 most recent rows with the lowest value of 'Low' from the whole table.

Comment: I do want to return a single row: it has to be the most recent record of the most recent 100 records with the Min low of the most recent 100 records. this query returns a single row, but it does NOT return the most recent record. It seems to find the Minlow of the most recent 100 records, but returns a record somewhere way prior to the most recent 100, that has the same Low value.

Comment: Your question stated otherwise: "Returns the row(s) with lowest value in column "Low" in the whole table." Did you try the latest update?

Comment: I got it : SELECT top 1 * From streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC where Low = (select min(Low) FROM (select Top 10 * from streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC order by OHLCid desc) as temp) order by OHLCid desc       would this be the most efficient way in doing this? this is a table that is updated and checked in milliseconds

Comment: Yes using TOP N ordered by a clustered index will be super quick and because you are only selecting 100 rows a very small section of the database will be searched. How fast is it running? Do you have a non-clustered index on Low and a clustered index on OHLCid?

Comment: with efficiency in mind; wouldn't it be possible to select the most recent 100 records first, and then look for the most recent of that result set that has the MinLow of those 100 records? what we do with the above query (if I understand correctly) is we find MinLow of the recent 100 reords, then re-iterate over the whole table and return Top1 with that MinLow value

Comment: You could do this instead: 
SELECT top 1 * 
From (select Top 100 * from streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC order by OHLCid desc) as x
where Low = 
(select min(Low) FROM (select Top 100 * from streamer.dbo.AAPL_OHLC order by OHLCid desc) as temp)

It will only look through the top 100 records

Comment: actually, I compared both queries against a 2million record table, and the first query is faster; under a second, while the last query (which supposedly only runs over the last 100 records) takes about 2 seconds. Both work as intended and return the same result.